# volatility term structure calibration

Tags: volatility, interest-rates, calibration, libor, hullwhite

As is well known in order to calibrate an interest rate model (i.e. hull-white, LMM) i need to use the current market yield curve and volatility. But in the case I want to calibrate the model in a market without caps that is without the vol TS what is the recommended proxy? How could I use information in other markets(that is another country or product) in order to develop a proxy volatility term structure?

Comment: You can calibrate your model on any available interest rate products, and your model will be good for pricing similar products.

Comment: In other words my questions is: how do I price caps in a market with only linear interest rate products i.e. CCS, IRS?